# Unable to delete apps off ACOSJ Card

Tags: java, memory, smartcard, javacard

I'm unable to delete an app off of my ACOSJ card. It was working okay until today when I started to get the 6F00 response to every command. I tried to delete the app with global platform pro and got the message 'Could not delete AID: xxxxxxxxxx'.

Why is it that I can't delete the app? Is it related to the fact that after using the app fine for a while I start getting a 6F00 response?

Comment: Which version of GlobalPlatformPro are you using? Are you deleting the package ID or the applet ID?

Comment: I'm using gpp version 325fe84. I'm trying to delete first the applet, then the package ID. The 'Could not delete' message comes when I try and delete the applet. If I try to delete the package first I get the 'some app still active?' message

Comment: 20.08.12 (325fe84) is a pre-release. Latest release is 20.1.23 (5ad373b) as there might be issue in the pre-release.  Other than that, not all cards are fully tested and supported and if the latest release wont work, making a ticket to on the github repository for GlobalPlatformPro is probably required.